# In Service Fabric, Are reliable queues only available to the same service type?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I created a pair of services in service fabric, one goes and reads from the source database and if it finds any new items, adds to a reliable queue; the other one tries to dequeue from the reliable queue and creates in the other database where I need the records.

If both of this processes are in the same service, everything works, but if I separate this functionality in two different services, the second service queue is always empty, which tells me the queues are not the same.

Hence my question: is a reliable queue only available to instances of the same service type? Is there any way to make a reliable queue available to two or more service types? If I want to share the same queue across service types, do I have to use Service Bus instead?

I hope my question makes sense, I have been trying to find this in the documentation, but I do not see anything helpful there, maybe I am looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reliable collection is indeed only available to one particular stateful service type. The whole idea behind it is that the data (reliable collection) lives where the code (service) lives.

If you want to access the queue from another service you could expose methods that manipulate the queue to do that on the service interface and have other services call this service. See [this repo](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors) for some inspiration. Or use another messaging service like the Azure Service Bus or Azure Storage Queues.